# Modifying Dijkstra for counting

Tags: python, algorithm, graph

I read somewhere that it was possible to modify Dijkstra's algorithm to count the number of shortest paths between two vertices. If this were my implementation of Dijkstra's algorithm, how could I modify it to count?

```
def dijkstra(G, s, t):
    D, P = {}, {}
    Q = {v: float('inf') for v in G}
    Q[s] = 0

    for v in Q:
        D[v] = Q[v]
        if v == t: break

        for w in G[v]:
            if D[v] + G[v][w] < Q[w]:
                P[w] = v
                Q[w] = D[v] + G[v][w]
    return D, P
```

Is it as simple as incrementing a counter when `D[v] + G[v][w] = Q[w]` and resetting the counter when it's less than `Q[w]`?

Comment: If the code you've posted were your implementation of Dijkstra's algorithm, your implementation would be wrong. `Q` isn't a priority queue, and `for v in Q` doesn't pick the vertex with the lowest value each time.

Comment: @user2357112 Ah, I'll fix that when I'm writing the counting algorithm, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it as simple as incrementing a counter when D[v] + G[v][w] = Q[w] and resetting the counter when it's less than Q[w]?

Not quite. If `D[v] + G[v][w] == G[w]`, that doesn't mean you've found *one* provisionally-shortest path to w. After all, there might be multiple shortest paths to v, and each one gives you a provisionally-shortest path to w. You need to add v's counter value to w's counter. Also, if you reset w's counter, you reset it to v's counter value, not 0.

Comment: So a dictionary `C` of counters keyed by the vertex. Each time `D[v] + G[v][w] = Q[w]` then `C[w] += C[v] + 1` and when `D[v] + G[v][w] < Q[w]` then `C[w] = C[v]`?

Comment: @Nick: No `+1`. There's no extra shortest path to account for. You'll need to initialize `C[s] = 1`, if that clears things up any.

Comment: That gets me some results that look decent (after removing the break line). I don't have the answer for my input to check, but thanks for pointing me in the right direction.